# Show name of fields in message in Input Array Validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have array of dropdown with the same name what i'm trying to do is 
to display the actual name of the field when the error is displayed but now it is displaying like

> attributes.Size Attributes Fields are required

where size is the title that i'm passing dynamically

but i want actual name which i am passing as a title to an array.

Code:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
 'attributes.*' => 'required',
 ],[
 'attributes.*.required' => ':attribute Attributes Fields are required.',
 ]);

 {!! Form::select('attributes['.$attr->title.']') !!}
```

Comment: Very difficult to understand. I would like to suggest a better grammar.

Comment: I'm getting validation errors for required array field as index values, but i want actual name.

Comment: Instead of making a custom validator, you could use a FormRequest and use the message() methods to display a custom message.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation